# SQL Server trigger calculation unit price how?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, triggers

I need a trigger for a SQL Server database in order to calculate unit price. Database table name `OrnekTbl` and columns names are

```
TotalPrice 
Quantity
UnitPrice
```

How can I update `UnitPrice` when I save the `TotalPrice` and `Quantity`?

Comment: Which Sql rdbms please? Also, why not either 1) calculate the totalprice in your app when you insert it (or in an Insert Proc) or 2) Consider a computed column and save space. Triggers should never be a first choice solution.

Comment: I agree with @StuartLC - I don't know why you want to store it at all: either use a computed column or calculate it in your app, either when you retrieve that row or as a `UnitPrice` property which only has a Getter that does this calculation in the object the row creates.

Comment: Thanks for you kind interest. i try to write program in visual basic. when i save the totalprice and quantity, i see the values in my gridview and sql database. in my gridview i see the calculation of unitprice but sql database nothing..i thought that in order to solve this problem i need trigger

Comment: **SQL** is a **query language** - but **NOT** a database..... so there really is no **SQL database** - there are databases using SQL - yes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've read the above caveats in the comment, and assuming that you are on Sql Server, and assuming you have some sort of key on OrnekTbl (I've used `Name`):

```
CREATE TRIGGER t_CalcUnitPrice ON OrnekTbl FOR INSERT, UPDATE AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE o
      -- Depending on the various types of your columns, CAST(x as DECIMAL(N, M)) may be needed
      SET o.UnitPrice = i.TotalPrice / i.Quantity
      FROM 
         INSERTED i 
           INNER JOIN OrnekTbl o 
           ON i.Name = o.Name
      WHERE i.Quantity > 0; -- Avoid Div Zero
END;
```

But I wouldn't really want to be the maintenance dev on your App FWIW - triggers work behind the scenes and hence not immediately obvious w.r.t. understanding and readability.

Comment: sql server, TotalPrice (money)
Quantity("nvarchar(50))
UnitPrice (money)

Comment: Quantity `NVARCHAR`? It's time to rethink your table structure.

Comment: what you recommend for Quantity?

Comment: @user3198433: Please don't forget to mark the question as answered if it helped you!